# How to create a fresh test database at startup

Tags: arangodb

Building my CI tests and would like to get a fresh database on every start. How can I tell arango to reset/clear/clean the database and initialize say a "test" db.

`arangodb --starter.local --starter.port=8529 start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I usually do something like that:

1. Run ArangoDB in a docker container. The Arango official image is easy to use and you can create containers that can either keep the data or start empty every time. The official image can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb/)
2. Create a Foxx micro service and populate the setup and a teardown scripts. These scripts run automatically when you install/upgrade/replace the service. The setup could create the necessary tables. The teardown could remove related tables. You can learn more about these life cycle scripts [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/foxx-guides-scripts.html#lifecycle-scripts)